# Find the angle between parallel lines

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to solve the following problem. 
Given: $$\overleftrightarrow{AB} \parallel \overleftrightarrow{DE}$$
And the measures of angles $$\angle BAC = 42 ^{\circ}$$ 
$$\angle EDC= 54 ^{\circ}$$ 
Find the measure of angle $$\angle ACD$$ 
How would you approach to solve the problem. I have tried as recommended on book to assume that there is one parallel line passing through point $C$, but i couldn't produce an answer. What is your advice?

Attached follows the geometric representation[image: Figure 1 Geometric Model]

Comment: Draw a line through $C$ which is parallel to the other lines.  Then the angle you want is the sum of 2 angles whose measure are easy to find.

Comment: @Paul I appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a line perpendicular to $AB$ and $DE$ passing through $C$. Say this line meets $AB$ at $X$ and $DE$ at $Y$. Then using the two right-angled triangles, $\angle ACX=90-42=48^{\circ}$ and $\angle DCY=90-54=36^{\circ}$. Since angles on a straight line sum to $180^{\circ}$, $\angle ACD=180-48-36=96^{\circ}$.

Comment: On the same figure if we make $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ Transversal and draw parallel line $l$ through point $C$, this seems that angle between Transversal $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and parallel line $l$ is congruent to $\angle BAC$

Comment: i mean inner right angle between Transversal $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and parallel line $l$

Comment: @JFC Yes, you're right, because alternate angles are equal

Comment: Thanks for the answer.